# Google Sheet (Script) copy Sheet to another SpreadSheet and name new sheet in target SS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am not that good in script cause i begin, so i want to copy a sheet from a SpreadSheet (source) and copy it to my target SpreadSheet by creating a new sheet (in target SS) and name it with my value in cell C9 in my source sheet....

Actually the new sheet is create with the new name but nothing Copy in the target sheet. It seem to be my .copyTo(targetrange) who as the problem... I try a lot of think but nothing works.

can you help me!

````
function CopyToSpreadSheet() {

//Source sheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reception");
//Name new sheet in target SpreadSheet from value in cell C9
var nameSheet = sourceSheet.getRange(9, 3).getValue();

    //open target SpreadSheet
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadSheet_Id');
    var newSheet = target.insertSheet();
    var Sheetname = newSheet.setName(nameSheet).getSheetName();
    //CopyTo...  
    var targetSheet = target.getSheetByName(nameSheet);
    var targetrange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, targetSheet.getLastColumn()+1);
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, 80, 15).copyTo(targetrange).getValues();
    targetrange.setValues(sourceRange);
    
    
    return;
    
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The `copyTo` method is available for Sheet Objects and for Range Objects. If you want to use it on a Range instance as you are doing at:

```
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, 80, 15).copyTo(targetrange).getValues();
```

It has a limitation: you cannot copy a range to a different Spreadsheet.

### Proposed modification

You can use the `copyTo` method of a Sheet instance in order to achieve the desired result:

```
function CopyToSpreadSheet() {

  //Source sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reception");
  //Name new sheet in target SpreadSheet from value in cell C9
  var nameSheet = sourceSheet.getRange(9, 3).getValue();

  //open target SpreadSheet
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('target-sheet-id');

  //CopyTo...
  var targetSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(target);
  targetSheet.setName(nameSheet);
    
  return;
}
```

### Reference

[Sheet copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))

Comment: I don't know exactly why but i receive this popup : 
Exception: The Spreadsheets service failed while accessing the document with the identifier 1DGv6CqLkry0uaLqN-HRRX0dODvBEr2qk... This identifier is ma sourceSheet...

Comment: Is the spreadsheet you are trying to open available? Please check again the spreadsheet ID.

Comment: In the example the sheet identifier is the target Spreadsheet not the source. The source it's being accessed via the `.getActiveSpreadsheet()` method called in a bound Apps Script project.

Comment: Ok i got it, but 1DGv6CqLkry0uaLqN-HRRX0dODvBEr2qk is my ID for my SS. 
The error occurs when .getActiveSpreadsheet is activated either directly at the start. It's like my script can't have permission to open the active sheet. What could be preventing the script from reaching my active sheet? Thx for your help!

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code you are using now?

Comment: ``` function CopyToSpreadSheet() {

  //Source sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reception");
  //Name new sheet in target SpreadSheet from value in cell C9
  var nameSheet = sourceSheet.getRange(9, 3).getValue();

  //open target SpreadSheet
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1j393AYnm5gxHXOUNEqCUwdjj2pr0dGBjXKT4JFhHr');

  //CopyTo...
  var targetSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(target);
  targetSheet.setName(nameSheet);
    
  return;
}```

Comment: *Ok i got it, but 1DGv6CqLkry0uaLqN-HRRX0dODvBEr2qk is my ID for my SS. The error occurs when .getActiveSpreadsheet is activated either directly at the start. * 

So the target and the source are the same spreadsheet?

Comment: Ok let's try to trouble shoot your issue:
- Do you own both Spreadsheets?
- Can you authorize the script successfully?
Apparently this error presents in this condition:is usually an error message one obtains when hitting the maximum size limit for a spreadsheet. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62298160/7453656)

- Is this your case?

Comment: I own the booth Spreadsheet. I've reduce my table to don't get this issue but still no working. But I send just the Values and it's works. My problem is to update values in the new sheet creat in target...

Comment: You want to update the values or create a copy as a new sheet? Can you please share the input and the desired output?

Comment: I find the it, it was me... i forgot a code line to erase in my function...Sorry. I realy appreciate your help. Thx